# CTRL + ALT + F1 : is it possible to screen capture it?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, screenshot

I like using the pure text mode by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>:<kbd>F6</kbd>), but I need to take screenshots of it too.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: digital camera?

Comment: @pierrely , vanadium's answer is more elegant.

Comment: I would say "more beautified" @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. However, if you need to take screenshots of terminal output, there are two alternatives, the first being by far the most straightforward and easiest.

1. Run `gnome-terminal` instead. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to have it full screen. This feels essentially like a full screen text terminal. Take screenshots the usual way.
2. Run your operating system in a virtual machine instead (this is the "guest"). Take screenshots of the guest in the host system (the operating system that is started on your computer when you turn it on).

   For example, in "Boxes", <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> will transfer the keyboard to the host. Then hit the shortcut key to take a screenshot of the screen (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> in Ubuntu 22.04). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to return all keyboard input back to the guest.

Comment: Or you can run it in a virtual machine like VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation player :)